# I want to print the elements of the C++ vector in a listbox in the C# form application

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I wrote a C ++ dll. One of the dll's functions returns the vector it takes as a parameter as follows

```
 std::vector<std::string> foo(std::vector<std::string> strVec) {return strVec;}
```

I want to write the elements of the vector, which is the return value of the above function, into the listbox named lstData on the C# side.How can I do that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you can't just "pass" a C++ vector to C# code as is. You need to write some sort of interop layer, either P/Invoke (like the linked answer shows) or C++/CLI. Once that's done, then the rest is just trivial enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `std::vector<std::string>` is a c++ object. P/Invoke calls c-style functions and have no understanding of c++ objects. Your alternatives are more or less

1. Add a method to you c++ dll that accepts/returns pointers or c-style arrays.
2. Write a c++/cli adapter that converts between the vector and a C# list/array.